# MS Dynamics CRM 4 - The current configuration system does not support user-scoped settings

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have register my plugin to MSCRM 4.0. When I revise or close quote, error will appear. See it below

[image: Error]

**Log from event viewer**

> The description for Event ID 18176 from source MSCRMWebService cannot
>   be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed
>   on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can
>   install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> 3fcb582d-1ab7-dd11-9382-001cc4e015ee
>   f21001ba-1ee5-e011-8cb3-02bfac1e2a4b quoteclose 50 Create
>   AAA.Microsoft.CRM.Plugin.CloseddateToQuote, CloseddateToQuote,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0b2965a625ff0115
>   AAA.Microsoft.CRM.Plugin.CloseddateToQuote Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The current
>   configuration system does not support user-scoped settings.    at
>   System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext
>   context, SettingsPropertyCollection properties)    at
>   System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(SettingsProvider
>   provider)    at
>   System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String
>   propertyName)    at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String
>   propertyName)    at
>   System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(String
>   propertyName)    at
>   System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String
>   propertyName)    at
>   CloseddateToQuote.Properties.Settings.get_CloseddateToQuote_CrmSdk_CrmService()
>   at
>   AAA.Microsoft.CRM.Plugin.CloseddateToQuote.Execute(IPluginExecutionContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.PluginStep.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext
>   context)

**Have anyone know the root cause? and How to simulate this error ?**

**How to solve it?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your plugin uses the Settings file, which to my knowledge isn't supported in plugins.  If you need to pass configuration to your plugin, you can do so using the [unsecure/secure parameters in your plugin constructor.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc468424.aspx)

You can then register configuration text (such as XML) in the PluginRegistrationTool.  In your plugin constructor, parse the unsecured/secure parameters and save them to local backing fields for use in your Execute method.